# AsyncTask doesn't execute when trying to clean HTML with HtmlCleaner

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, htmlcleaner

I'm trying to clean HTML with HtmlCleaner using AsyncTask. This is the code:

```
private class cleanHtml extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
            String url = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/263/razredi/16515";
            TagNode node = cleaner.clean(new URL(url));
            CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
            new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(node, "cleaned.xml", "utf-8");
            Log.i("TAG", "Executing AsyncTask");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm executing AsyncTask in onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    new cleanHtml().execute();

}//End of onCreate
```

However, nothing happens. As you can see I put log.i inside the AsyncTask to see if it is executing r not and I never see the log.i message inside logcat. What could I be doing wrong? Also, where in my phone will "cleaned.xml" appear? Since I didn't set any kind of destination folder.

Logcat (info):

```
09-25 20:23:31.739: W/System.err(19078): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /cleaned.xml: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
09-25 20:23:31.747: W/System.err(19078):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
09-25 20:23:31.747: W/System.err(19078):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
09-25 20:23:31.747: W/System.err(19078):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at org.htmlcleaner.Serializer.writeToFile(Serializer.java:131)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at org.htmlcleaner.Serializer.writeToFile(Serializer.java:142)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at com.whizzapps.stpsurniki.ScheudeleWithDesign$cleanHtml.doInBackground(ScheudeleWithDesign.java:36)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at com.whizzapps.stpsurniki.ScheudeleWithDesign$cleanHtml.doInBackground(ScheudeleWithDesign.java:1)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
09-25 20:23:31.755: W/System.err(19078):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
09-25 20:23:31.763: W/System.err(19078):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
```

Comment: Could be that you are getting an exception that is caught by the catch-block preventing your app from crashing. Post your LogCat output.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Which "kind" of LogCat output should I post? verbose/debug/info/...?

Comment: The one you get when the task is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The AsncTask is executed.** But the execution is not brought to an end because of an exception.

You are getting a `FileNotFoundEcxeption` in this line:

```
 new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(node, "cleaned.xml", "utf-8");
```

which is caught by your catch-block preventing your app from crashing.

The Exception could be **caused by:**

- The path to the "cleaned.xml" file not being correct.
- Typos int he filename.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you have any idea how to fix this? This file isn't supposed to exist anyway, it's supposed to be created when the execution finishes. If you've ever worked with HtmlCleaner before I'd appreciate it.